# Java Generics - Check type of T

Tags: java, generics

I am using a method like this

```
private static <T> void setPreference(String key, T value)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Controller.getContext());

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString(key, value.toString());

    editor.commit();
}
```

Unfortunately, `putString` is one of multiple put methods.  I also want to use `putBoolean` and `putInt`.  My problem is that I want to support the specific types (I don't want to save everything as a string like I am doing), and I want to reduce code duplication as much as possible.  I'm used to C# where this kind of thing is very easy, so I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Why aren't you using subclassing, then, and not generics, if you want to support each type explicitly as opposed to supporting any type?

Comment: I wanted to keep it simple.  This class is a helper class with all static methods that access the android preferences manager.  The goal is so I can do `PreferencesHelper.setMyPref(value)` or `PreferencesHelper.getMyPref()` and my helper manages my keys and the logic around setting and getting the values (and casting them into their appropriate types).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `if (value instanceof Boolean) { editor.putBoolean(..); }`.

But that's not quite OO. What you can do is move the responsibility to the value object:

```
public intarface ValueHolder<T> {
     void putInEditor(String key, Editor editor);
     T getValue();
}

public class StringValueHolder extends ValueHolder<String> {
    private String value;
    // constructor here to initialize the value
    public putInEditor(String key, Editor editor) {
        editor.putString(key, value);
    }

    public String getValue() {
         return value;
    }
}

public class BooleanValueHolder extends ValueHolder<Boolean> {
    private Boolean value;
    // constructor here to initialize the value
    public putInEditor(String key, Editor editor) {
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    }

    public Boolean getValue() {
         return value;
    }
}
```

It's more verbose, I agree, so If you don't want to complicate things, stick with the `instanceof` solution.

Comment: I guess it is right way. One more question is it strategy pattern?

Answer (score 6):

Make several overloads: one that accepts `<T extends Boolean>`, etc, for each of the specific types you want to carve out.